# Plot not working

Tags: plotting

I am trying to generate a plot for `S2[w]`. My code is below

```
L := 50
Umc := 4.31
Su[ω_, σ_, τ_] := (σ^2 *τ/π )*1/(1 \
+ (τ *ω)^2)
Sw[ω_, σ_, τ_] := (σ^2 *τ/(2*π \
))*(1 + 3*(τ* ω)^2)/(1 + (τ*ω)^2)^2

Ru[s_] := InverseFourierTransform[Su[ω, 1, L/Umc], ω, s]

S2 [ω_] := Integrate[Ru[s]*Cos[2*ω*s], {s, 0, Infinity}]

Plot[S2[ω] , {ω, 0, 1}]
```

I have no idea what I am doing wrong. The function outputs number for the prescribed range when I tested. Your help would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Change to `Plot[Evaluate@S2[\[Omega]], {\[Omega], 0, 1}, PlotRange -> All]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Plot[Evaluate@S2[ω], {ω, 0, 1}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

BTW, generally a bad idea to use symbols with capitalized initials - you risk clashing with built-in symbols...

Comment: thanks for the help...if I want to plot another function `S3[w]` on the same graph then can you please help me with this? I tried `Plot[{Evaluate@S2[\[Omega]], Evaluate@S3[\[Omega]]}, {\[Omega], 0, 1},
  PlotRange -> All]` but it doesn't work. where `S3[\[Omega]] = Integrate[Ru[s]*Cos[\[Omega]*s], {s, 0, Infinity}]`...also I would like to have the x axis in log scale...can you please help with this? thanks

Comment: @Stoc `Evaluate` should be placed at the first level inside the function with a `Hold*` attribute you wish to cancel (`Plot` in this case): `Plot[Evaluate@{S2[\[Omega]], S3[\[Omega]]}, {\[Omega], 0, 1}, PlotRange -> All]`.

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov Thank you so much again....I have yet again one more problem, I am trying to do a LogLog plot and I am using: `LogLogPlot[Evaluate@S2[\[Omega]], {\[Omega], 0, 1}]` but there is an error...can you please help with this? sorry for the bother

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov also, if I use your variant above (i.e., `LogLogPlot[Evaluate@{S2[\[Omega]], S3[\[Omega]]}, {\[Omega], 0, 1}, PlotRange -> All]`) for many plots then will it still work? I'll really appreciate the help...just need this result

Comment: @Stoc Please read the error messages *carefully*, they contain key information what you are doing wrong and how to do it right. In the case of `LogLogPlot` you get the message "Range specification {ω,0,1} is not of the form {x, xmin, xmax} with xmin and xmax positive." which simply means that you must specify the plotting range with positive boundaries because `Log` is `Real` only for positive argument. So you should use something like `LogLogPlot[Evaluate@S2[\[Omega]], {\[Omega], 0.01, 1}]`. Answering your second question, yes, it should work.

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov thank you so much...im silly!