# Plot Taylor expansion of polynomial

Tags: plotting, series-expansion

I have a polynomial:

```
f[x_] := x^3 + 2*x^2 + 4
```

and I create a function that implements the Taylor expansion:

```
ft[x_, x0, n] := Normal[Series[f[x], {x, x0, n}]]
```

If I implement the expansion, the output is as expected:

```
ft[x, 5, 2]
```

(*179 + 95 (-5 + x) + 17 (-5 + x)^2*)

If I then plot the output, it works as expected:

```
Plot[179 + 95 (-5 + x) + 17 (-5 + x)^2, {x, -10, 10}]
```

But if I do it in one step, I obtain an error:

```
Plot[{f[x], ft[x, 5, 2]}, {x, 0, 10}]
```

(*General::stop: Further output of General::ivar will be suppressed during this calculation.*)

- Why causes this error?
- How I can solve it keeping the one step approach? I know there are examples such as [this one](https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/1778315), but they use multiple steps.

Comment: Search for “ivar Plot” on this site for answers.  Here’s one such Q&A: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1301/4999. What happens is that your functions aren’t evaluated until after Plot gives x a numerical value. In effect it’s evaluating Series[f[0.], {0., 5, 2}] etc.

Comment: Hi, you can reduce your problem to "why is my plot not working" (removing the Taylor expansion back story). Although I knew the answer to the problem, I was curious how quickly one could find the answer here as it is one of the most popular issues. I typed "plot not working" in the search box and found a question entitled [plot not working](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/44545/86543) that should solve this problem. Learning to search for solutions here is a valuable skill to have that will allow you to get solutions to your problems a lot faster.

Comment: That said, I am actually curious as to why I actually do not get an error. Maybe something changed in the version that I have 13.1

Comment: For more common issues one can encounter using Mathematica there is this [question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/18393/what-are-the-most-common-pitfalls-awaiting-new-users)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
f[x_] := x^3 + 2*x^2 + 4
ft[x_, x0_, n_] := Normal[Series[f[x], {x, x0, n}]]

ft[x, 5, 2]
```

> 179 + 95 (-5 + x) + 17 (-5 + x)^2

```
Plot[{f[x], Evaluate@ft[x, 5, 2]}, {x, 0, 10}]
```

[image]